# Why does Sebulba's voice before and during the race sound so different?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

I noticed that Sebulba's voice is very low in pitch before the race, and it is much higher *during* the race. Why is it so?

Comment: Because he's excited?

Comment: @Valorum That's it?

Comment: @Valorum So he manages to retain his excitement even after Anakin crashed his podracer? ("Poodoo!")

Comment: Anakin was probably force choking him during the race. Cheeky devil

Comment: <mod removes comments> **[Being Nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)** is one of the conditions of using this site. Don't be rude.

Comment: @Valorum Look: "Because he's excited?" vs. "Probably because he was excited."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the race Sebulba is very relaxed: he's getting a manicure (pedicure?) from some beautiful alien ladies, and is trying to impress them with a deeper, more powerful voice.

During the race Sebulba is tense and stressed. Anxiety and stress can have an impact on the pitch of a person's voice. And pod racing, even if you're experienced, will most certainly raise your stress levels